# Term to describe initial investment versus long term gains

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

I'm looking for a word (or phrase) to describe a situation that takes a lot of time and effort to set up initially, but the initial costs are (ideally) offset by the long-term gains.

Specifically I'm looking to implement new project management tools: they will take a lot of time and effort to implement, and the value won't be seen immediately, but down the road I would expect to see enough value from the implementation to justify the effort.

I feel like there is a term and it's been on the tip of my tongue but for the life of me I can't find it.

Comment: The early part is a *steep learning curve*.

Comment: ROI - "return on investment"?

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance.  The term you had been thinking of will come to you one morning around 3 am!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your investment is ***far-sighted***, and will pay off in the medium to long term. *

**far-sighted**, from [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/farsighted)

> Planning prudently for the future; foresighted: large goals that
>   required farsighted policies.

Example, the successful development of [South Beach](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/South+Beach%3A+Florida%27s+gayest+beach+district+gets+yet+another+second+...-a0140054612):

> By now, the riches-to-rags-and-back-again saga of South Beach is
>   familiar to many. The areas first real boom got rolling in the
>   Mafia-fueled Roaring Twenties, and all those sophisticated art deco
>   buildings of the 1930s were built for a Jewish clientele driven
>   uptown. By the '70s the deteriorating deco district had become known
>   as "God's waiting room," full of old folks, crime, and drugs.
>   Preservationists and **farsighted developers** launched a heroic revival
>   in the late '80s, with an assist from NBC's Miami Vice, and voile, a
>   sun- and sex-soaked hot spot was born, christened South Beach.

- I am avoiding "in the long run" because "in the long run we are all dead". (Keynes)

Comment: I like this a lot. It isn't the phrase I had been thinking of, but it works well and I'm going to accept this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would call it a **good investment** or a **worthwhile investment**, or **something that will pay for itself many times over**. If there is a more appropriate word or phrase it escapes me at the moment.

Comment: That's awfully close to what I'm looking for, but not quite. I feel like it's definitely an investment term.

Comment: "Will have a positive ROI", perhaps?